# CRM plugin PreImage not updating related entity

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm

I'm fairly new to developing but I've encountered a problem when creating a plugin for Dynamics CRM. The plugin is supposed to render the parentcustomerid field null on contact entity when the account entity it is linked to is updated when the field primarycontactid is updated to something else, either that be null on linked to another contact.

With the code I have written currently no errors are thrown and the code is executed successful but parentcustomerid field still contains the account it is linked too when it should remove the link.

Here is the code i have currently:

```
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {       
            ITracingService tracingService = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));


            //Obtain the execution context
            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

            //obtain organizational services
            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

            EntityReference prePCID;
            Entity PreImage;
            // The InputParameters collection contains all the data passed in the message request.
            if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") &&
                context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
            {
                // Obtain the image entity from the Pre Entity Images.
                tracingService.Trace
                    ("trace1: Getting the target entity from Input Parameters.");
                PreImage = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

                // Verify that the target entity represents an account.
                // If not, this plug-in was not registered correctly.
                tracingService.Trace
                   ("trace2: Verifying that the target entity represents a account.");
                if (PreImage.LogicalName == "account")
                {
                    if (PreImage.Attributes.Contains("primarycontactid"))
                    {
                        tracingService.Trace
                            ("trace3: Setting the primary contact id in the prePCID.");
                    //prePCID = (EntityReference)PreImage.Attributes["primarycontactid"];
                    prePCID = (EntityReference)PreImage["primarycontactid"];

                        tracingService.Trace
                            ("trace4: Primary Contact Name: " + prePCID.Name + " Creating a variable that stores the contact using the prePCID.");
                        Entity contactToRemoveReference = service.Retrieve("contact", prePCID.Id, new ColumnSet("parentcustomerid")) as Entity;
                        tracingService.Trace
                            ("trace5: Removes the id: " + prePCID.Id + " of the parentcustomerid.");
                        contactToRemoveReference.Attributes["parentcustomerid"] = null;

                        service.Update(contactToRemoveReference);
                        tracingService.Trace
                            ("trace6: Execution Successful.");
                    }
                } 

        }
```

}

If anyone could solve this issue for me, that would be great thanks.

Comment: How is your plugin registered?

Comment: The message is update, the primary entity is account. when i registered the step it was set to pre-op

Comment: the preimage is filtered to primarycontactid as is the step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are populating Entity variable **PreImage** from primary entity in the input parameters.
I think you should get it from Pre image like:

```
Entity PreImage;
if (context.PreEntityImages.Contains("yourPreImageName") && context.PreEntityImages["yourPreImageName"] != null)
{
    PreImage = context.PreEntityImages["yourPreImageName"];
}
```